# Problem with the proxy using ZAP Docker Image GitLab

Tags: docker, proxy, gitlab, gitlab-ci, zap

I'm trying to use ZAP in my GitLab repository. (link to the docker image for ZAP: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Docker)

After running the specific CLI command, i get this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: http://zap/JSON/ascan/action/scan/?apikey=&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftargetwebsite%2Flanding&recurse=False (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f83a9dcc588>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)))
```

Has anyone already had the same problem or knows how I could solve it? Thank you all!

Comment: If it is a proxy issue try to add proxy with EXPORT HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY so that connection establishes with internet using the proxy

Comment: You can also set the upstream proxy in the ZAP configs.

Comment: @Sahit also with that, i get the same error

Comment: @SimonBennetts how can i do that via GitLab?

Comment: You'd probably have to ask gitlab...

Comment: @mdem99 How did you solve it ? I am getting same error.

Comment: @PardeepBeniwal was long time ago, i don't quite remember :) But if i'm correct, it was a port already in use. I managed to change the port number and solve the problem (but again, not sure if this solved this issue) :)

Comment: yes, @mdem99 there was port issue. I was updated the port after that its work fine.